# Use Join to Create a View Showing Sales, Returns and Profit (Sales - Returns) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have the following tables as part of a bigger Schema in MySQL Workbench 8.0CE;

**Orders** - Order_ID, Customer_ID, Payment_ID, Delivery_ID, Order_Date, Cost_Price_Eur, Sales_Tax_Eur, 
             Total_Price_Eur

**Returns** - Return_ID, Order_ID, Product_ID, Payment_ID, Return_Date, Reason_for_Return, 
              Quantity_Returned, Return_Value_Eur

I'm trying to create a view to show cumulative sales, returns and profit (sales less returns) each month. However, I'm having trouble with my script. I'm currently getting the following;

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZNLi.png)

The issues here are;

1) October and November are not coming in despite their being orders and returns in both months. Interestingly, the value of returns outweighs that of orders for both months so it may be a reason why.

2) The profit is returning as 0 rather than the difference between sales and returns.

My script is currently;

```
Create view Trading_Summary as
SELECT 
       a.Month_, 
       ifnull(a.Sales_,0) as Sales,
       ifnull(b.Returns_,0) as Returns,
       ifnull(c.Profit_,0) as Profit
FROM 
  (SELECT 
   SUM(Total_Price_Eur) as Sales_, monthname(Order_Date) as Month_
   FROM orders
   GROUP BY Month_) a
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 
   SUM(Return_Value_Eur) as Returns_, monthname(Return_Date) as Month_
   FROM returns
   GROUP BY Month_) b
    on a.Month_ = b.Month_
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT 
    SUM(Profit) as Profit_, Month_ FROM
    (SELECT 
    orders.Total_Price_Eur-returns.Return_Value_Eur as Profit, monthname(orders.Order_Date) as Month_
    FROM orders
INNER JOIN
     returns ON 
    orders.Order_ID = returns.Order_ID) B 
  GROUP BY Month_) c on 
     a.Month_ = c.Month_
```

Any help with this would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be you have not all the month try join the UNION for your table

```
select t1.Month_, ifnull(a.Sales_,0), ifnull(b.Returns_,0),  ifnull(a.Sales_,0) - ifnull(b.Returns_,0) Profit
from (
  select  monthname(Order_Date) as Month_
  from orders
  UNION 
  select  monthname(Order_Date) 
  from returns
  ) t1 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
   SUM(Total_Price_Eur) as Sales_, monthname(Order_Date) as Month_
   FROM orders
   GROUP BY Month_) a ON t1.Month_ = a.Month_
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
     SUM(Return_Value_Eur) as Returns_, monthname(Return_Date) as Month_
     FROM returns
   GROUP BY Month_
  ) b ON ON t1.Month_ = b.Month_
```

Comment: That worked a treat scaisEdge - thanks ever so much